# How to get average from a measure in Power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In my data source I have column Quoted and Submitted.

Dividing the `Sum(Quoted)` by `SUM(Submitted)` gives us `Sub to Quote` ratio.

So I have created a measure that divides Quoted/Submitted.

```
Sub to Quote = DIVIDE([Total Quoted], [Total Submitted])
```

Now, how can I simply have Average of that ratio?

[image]

So instead of `9%`, I need to see `8.18%`

.**PBIX** file can be accessed here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ug932qjju7zahfs/ClearanceDateNewWithCatalytic1.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
Sub to Quote =
AVERAGEX(
    SUMMARIZE(dim_Date,
        dim_Date[Qtr Year],
        "Average", DIVIDE( [Total Quoted], [Total Submitted] )
    ),
    [Average]
)
```

This summarizes your table to get the average for each quarter and then averages those averages.

Note: This returns `8.15%` rather than `8.18%`. I'm guessing this is just a rounding difference though.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you